# HTML / JS: Define onClick and onAuxClick at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, mouseevent

So it seems like Chrome and Firefox introduced [onAuxClick](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/auxclick) (Chrome as of Chrome 55).  This is intended to be like onClick but for non-primary buttons (i.e. middle and left click).

I have a lot of HTML code which is something like this:

```
<div onClick="someFunc(event);">Click here with either left or middle click</div>
```

(SomeFunc, of course, has some code which does slightly different things depending on if it is a middle or left click).

The addition of onAuxClick broke all of this code because middle click is no longer firing the onClick function.  Thanks for being super annoying, Chrome and Firefox!

Anyway, is there anything I can replace onClick with that will still fire both events?  Something like:

```
<div onAnyClick="someFunc(event);">Click here with either left or middle click</div>
```

Or is the solution to now call duplicate functions everywhere, like this:

```
<div onClick="someFunc(event);" onAuxClick="someFunc(event);">Click here with either left or middle click</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an example made by mozilla. Check this fiddle out:

```js
// Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onauxclick

var button = document.querySelector('button'); 
var html = document.querySelector('html');

function random(number) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * number);
}

button.onclick = function() {
  var rndCol = 'rgb(' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ')';
  button.style.backgroundColor = rndCol;
};

button.onauxclick = function() {
  var rndCol = 'rgb(' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ')';
  button.style.color = rndCol;
}
```

```html
<button>
  Click Me!
</button>
```

Comment: So unfortunately the only solution is to add event handlers for both.  There is no "one event handler to rule them all" anymore?  That's obnoxious.  :(

Comment: At least for now. I am hoping this will be improved so that it would be similar to `KeyboardEvent` :)